# pyhf test-statistics with toys

Tags: statistics, pyhf

Dear pyhf creators and contributors, first of all let me thank you for taking the time to undertake this project, it has already been very useful to me in checking simple analyses and conclusions.

From the github page, I read that "Non-asymptotic calculators" are in the To-do list. The first part of my question is what is the current status for pyhf-integrated computations using toys?

The second part, is what is the most straight-forward way for someone to use the existing pyhf schema to produce computations with toys, in a pyhf model that has been provided with any nuisance parameters? Are the `pyhf.infer.hypotest` test-statistics, shown in the "Empirical Test Statistics" `hepdata_like` example, capable of handling all pyhf schema modifiers and full-fledged models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question. All APIs discussed in this answer correspond to [the `v0.6.0` API](https://pyhf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/api.html).

> The first part of my question is what is the current status for pyhf-integrated computations using toys?

As of [release `v0.6.0`](https://github.com/scikit-hep/pyhf/releases/tag/v0.6.0) support for pseudoexperiments (toys) has been added to `pyhf`. You asked your question back in December 2020 and `pyhf` `v0.6.0` was releases in February 2021, so at the time of asking toys were only available in dev releases.

> what is the most straight-forward way for someone to use the existing `pyhf` schema to produce computations with toys

In your situation the easiest way to use toys is through the [`pyhf.infer.hypotest`](https://pyhf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/_generated/pyhf.infer.hypotest.html) API using the `calctype='toybased'` kwarg (which is passed through to [`pyhf.infer.utils.create_calculator`](https://pyhf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/_generated/pyhf.infer.utils.create_calculator.html)). Both the high level interface through the `hypotest` API and the lower level interface through the `Calculator` API are explored in a bit more detail in the [Using Calculators "learn" example in the docs](https://pyhf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/notebooks/learn/UsingCalculators.html).

> Are the `pyhf.infer.hypotest` test-statistics, shown in the "Empirical Test Statistics" `hepdata_like` example, capable of handling all pyhf schema modifiers and full-fledged models?

Yes. The test statistics available are passed to `hypotest` through the `test_stat` kwarg ([shown here for the `AsymptoticCalculator`](https://pyhf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/_generated/pyhf.infer.calculators.AsymptoticCalculator.html), but they are the same as for the `ToyCalculator`).

Note that now the default documentation website will now be the one hosted and versioned with releases on ReadTheDocs: https://pyhf.readthedocs.io/. This should help avoid confusion in the future about what is in the current dev release and what is in the stable public release.